# Does Cython offer any reasonably easy and efficient way to iterate Numpy arrays as if they were flat?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

Let's say I want to implement Numpy's

```
x[:] += 1
```

in Cython. I could write

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparoundcheck(False)
def add1(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] x):
    cdef unsigned long i
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] += 1
```

However, this only works with `ndim = 1`. I could use

```
add1(x.reshape(-1))
```

but this only works with contiguous `x`.

**Does Cython offer any reasonably easy and efficient way to iterate Numpy arrays as if they were flat?**

(*Reimplementing this particular operation in Cython doesn't make sense, as the above Numpy's code should be as fast as it gets -- I'm just using this as a simple example*)

**UPDATE:**

I benchmarked the proposed solutions:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def add1_flat(np.ndarray x):
    cdef unsigned long i
    for i in range(x.size):
        x.flat[i] += 1

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def add1_nditer(np.ndarray x):
    it = np.nditer([x], op_flags=[['readwrite']])
    for i in it:
        i[...] += 1
```

The second function requires `import numpy as np` in addition to `cimport`. The results are:

```
a = np.zeros((1000, 1000))

b = a[100:-100, 100:-100]

%timeit b[:] += 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop

%timeit add1_flat(b)
1 loops, best of 3: 316 ms per loop

%timeit add1_nditer(b)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.11 s per loop
```

So, they are 300 and 1000 times slower than Numpy.

**UPDATE 2:**

The `add11` version uses a `for` loop inside of a `for` loop, and so doesn't iterate the array as if it were flat. However, it is as fast as Numpy in this case:

```
%timeit add1.add11(b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 ms per loop
```

On the other hand, `add1_unravel`, one of the proposed solutions, fails to modify the contents of `b`.

Comment: These timings are for the compiled cython code?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, unless I screwed up somehow (I'm new to Cython). These definitions are in myfile.pyx; setup.py includes setup(ext_modules =cythonize("myfile.pyx")), and I call "python setup.py build_ext --inplace" before importing myfile into ipython.

Comment: @hpaulj there's no way to tell Cython the type of x's elements. If I specify it, Cython assumes ndim=1. Plus, I think that flat and nditer are Python constructs that Cython just calls via Python

Comment: There is [numpy.ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) that might be suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Is a nice tutorial on using `nditer`.  It ends with a `cython` version. `nditer` is meant to be the all purpose array(s) iterator in numpy `c` level code.

There are also good array examples on the Cython memoryview page:

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html

The data buffer of an `ndarray` is a flat buffer.  So regardless of the array's shape and strides, you can iterate over the whole buffer in a flat `c` pointer fashion.  But things like  `nditer` and `memoryview` take care of the element size details.  So in `c` level coding it is actually easier to step through all the elements in a flat fashion than it is to step by rows - going by rows has to take into account the row stride.

This runs in Python, and I think it will translate nicely into cython (I don't have that setup on my machine at the moment):

```
import numpy as np

def add1(x):
   it = np.nditer([x], op_flags=[['readwrite']])
   for i in it:
       i[...] += 1
   return it.operands[0]

x = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
y = add1(x)
print(x)
print(y)
```

https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum/blob/master/sop.pyx is a sum-of-products script that I wrote a while back to simulate `einsum`.

The core of its `w = sop(x,y)` calculation is:

```
it = np.nditer(ops, flags, op_flags, op_axes=op_axes, order=order)
it.operands[nop][...] = 0
it.reset()
for xarr, yarr, warr in it:
    x = xarr
    y = yarr
    w = warr
    size = x.shape[0]
    for i in range(size):
       w[i] = w[i] + x[i] * y[i]
return it.operands[nop]
```

===================

copying ideas from the `nditer.html` document, I got a version of `add1` that is only half the speed of the native `numpy` `a+1`.  The naive `nditer` (above) isn't much faster in `cython` than in `python`.  A lot of the speedup may be due to the `external loop`.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def add11(arg):
   cdef np.ndarray[double] x
   cdef int size
   cdef double value
   it = np.nditer([arg],
        flags=['external_loop','buffered'], 
        op_flags=[['readwrite']])
   for xarr in it:
       x = xarr
       size = x.shape[0]
       for i in range(size):
           x[i] = x[i]+1.0
   return it.operands[0]
```

I also coded this `nditer` in python with a print of `size`, and found that it iterated on your `b` with 78 blocks of size 8192 - that's a buffer size, not some characteristic of `b` and its data layout.

```
In [15]: a = np.zeros((1000, 1000)) 
In [16]: b = a[100:-100, 100:-100]

In [17]: timeit add1.add11(b)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.48 ms per loop

In [18]: timeit b[:] += 1
100 loops, best of 3: 8.76 ms per loop

In [19]: timeit add1.add1(b)    # for the unbuffered nditer 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.1 s per loop

In [21]: timeit add1.add11(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll read thru the tutorials and see if they answer my question. I think the answer would be improved if it included an actual implementation of `x[:] += 1` (that is efficient, works with any number of dimensions and x that's not contiguous)

Comment: I've added a faster cython version.

Comment: It's a bit unsatisfying because the stated goal is to iterate `x` **as if it were flat**. Nested loops don't exactly do that, although perhaps your solution is about as good as it gets.

Comment: The only nesting here is determined by the `nditer` buffer size.  Check my edits.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `flat` attribute of the `ndarray`, which provides an iterator over the flattened array object. It always iterates in C-major ordering, with the last index varying the fastest. Something like:

```
for i in range(x.size):
    x.flat[i] += 1
```

Comment: Interesting, although I suspect pretty inefficient. I'll run some tests later.

Comment: @MaxB Seems like you're right about the inefficiency. A quick `%timeit` in IPython shows that it takes about 10% more time than just iterating over all the dimensions of the array. Also, I was incorrect about the ordering, the `flat` attribute always returns an iterator over the elements in C ordering.

Comment: Another option could be to create a reshaped view onto `x`'s memory and use the solution you proposed. E.g., `new_array = x.view().reshape(-1, 1)`.

Comment: AFAIK that doesn't work with non-contiguous arrays (I mention it in the question). Modifying the contents of a view, if it's not contiguous, does some kind of copy-on-write and the array it's viewing remains unchanged (I haven't tried it in Cython though) EDIT : actually, I suspect it copies at creation time

Answer (score 1):

With [numpy.ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)

> numpy.ravel(a, order='C')
>
> Return a contiguous flattened array.
>
> A 1-D array, containing the elements of the input, is returned. A copy
>   is made only if needed.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def add1_ravel(np.ndarray xs):
    cdef unsigned long i
    cdef double[::1] aview

    narray = xs.ravel()
    aview = narray

    for i in range(aview.shape[0]):
        aview[i] += 1

    # return xs if the memory is shared
    if not narray.flags['OWNDATA'] or np.may_share_memory(xs, narray):
        return xs

    # otherwise new array reshaped
    shape = tuple(xs.shape[i] for i in range(xs.ndim))
    return narray.reshape(shape)
```